# Grid.columns.editable not available where is wrong?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem with kendoGrid with `popup` editing. It displays value of first column as a label in popup even when I set editable property to false.

```
columns: [
    {
        template: kendo.template('<span>#: sys_index # </span>'),
        width: 38,
        editable: false
    }, {
        title: 'System Name',
        field: 'SystemName'
    }, {
        command: ['edit', 'destroy'], width: 200
    }
]
```

[rendered grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJ3lc.png)

[grid popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opaUe.png)

Comment: Welcame to stackoverflow. I redrafted your question to clarify your problem. If unnecessary label in grid popup is not your question, please edit it and specify your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Editability determines if the field value can be modified, but it will still appear in both cases. A possible option is to remove the readonly content in the Grid's `edit` event.

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#events-edit

http://dojo.telerik.com/ItUvA

Assuming that the readonly content is in the first column...

```
edit: function(e) {
    var form = e.container;
    form.find(".k-edit-label").eq(0).remove();
    form.find(".k-edit-field").eq(0).remove();
}
```